# Одномерный и двумерный массивы, функции в C

Tags: c

Есть задача: **Заполнить одномерный массив из 20 элементов из файла input.txt и вывести его на экран. Изменить элементы массива, разделив каждый элемент массива на произведение последних цифр предыдущего и следующего элемента. Вывести измененный массив на экран на новой строке.** Я написал код так, как я его понимаю, но он, к сожалению не работает.
Я перебираю элементы с 1 по N, с каждым элементом провожу действия промежуточные, ВРОДЕ БЫ, правильно. Программа завершается с ошибкой, но не пишет, какой. Я учел ошибки из предыдущего вопроса, поэтому старался сам решить проблему:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 5
int main() {
    FILE *output, *input;
    int array[N], i, pred, posl, proizv;
    output = fopen("input.txt", "w");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        array[i] = -100 + rand() % (100 + 100 + 1);
        fprintf(output, "%d ", array[i]);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        pred = array[i - 1] % 10;
        posl = array[i + 1] % 10;
        proizv = pred * posl;
        array[i] /= proizv;
    }

    fclose(output);
    return 0;
}
```

Есть идея разбить главный цикл на 2 цикла, чтоб считать отдельно все, потом из них составлять массивы, складывать элементы массивов, получать сумму.  В чем ошибки?

**Как решил:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 20
int main(void) {
    FILE *output;
    int i, array[N], pred, posl, proizv;
    output = fopen("output.txt", "w+r");
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        array[i] = -100 + rand() % (100 + 100 + 1);
        fprintf(output, "%d ", array[i]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        fscanf(output, "%d ", &array[i]);
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }
    fclose(output);
    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 1; i < N - 1; i++) {
        pred = array[i - 1] % 10;
        posl = array[i + 1] % 10;
        proizv = pred * posl;
        printf("%d *%d =%d\n", pred, posl, proizv);
    }
    printf("\n\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ну подумайте сами... `for (i = 0; i < N; i++) { pred = array[i - 1] % 10;` — ну вот **какое** у вас значение в `array[-1]`? Это просто выход за границы массива, как и `array[N]`. Понятно, что первый и последний элементы — у которых только по одному соседу! — должны обрабатываться иначе (например, не обрабатываться вообще).

Comment: Да, об этом знаю, их можно не обрабатывать. Я так понимаю, чтоб это сделать, надо ```for (i=1; i<N-1; i++)```.

Comment: @Harry, может быть, еще что-нибудь подскажете?

Answer (score 0):

> *@Harry, может быть, еще что-нибудь подскажете?*

Да в принципе, все сказано. Вот готовая программа, которая делает то, что написано в условии. Крайние значения не трогая. Читая ввод из файла, и выводя в файл.

Деление выполняю с плавающей точкой.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define N 20

int main()
{
    FILE *output, *input;
    input = fopen("input.txt", "rt");
    assert(input != NULL);
    output = fopen("output.txt", "wt");
    assert(output != NULL);

    int pred, curr, next;
    fscanf(input," %d %d",&pred,&curr);
    fprintf(output,"%d ", pred);
    for(int i = 1; i < N-1; i++)
    {
        fscanf(input," %d",&next);
        fprintf(output,"%lf ",((double)curr)/(pred%10)/(next%10));
        pred = curr, curr = next;
    }
    fprintf(output,"%d\n",next);

    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста, я подправил вопрос, там внизу код, как я решил эту задачу. Что скажете?